# How to get the list of all the direct parent of a node?

Tags: xpath

There is a `XML` generated from a X3 Sage application. I do not know its data neither its structures ; what I know is just the node names from which I will retrieve data ( the node's text ). In `XML` a node can appear more times ; and in that case the node is included inside a parent node ; for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<some_root>
   <some_parent_node>
      <some_node_1>some_data</some_node_1>
      <some_node_2>some_data</some_node_2>
   </some_parent_node>
   <some_parent_node>
      <some_node_1>some_data</some_node_1>
      <some_node_2>some_data</some_node_2>
   </some_parent_node>
</some_root>
```

I want to get all the direct parent node of the node `<some_node_1>`. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get direct parent node of each `some_node_1` node you can try

```
//some_node_1/parent::*
```

If you want to get all *ancestor nodes*:

```
//some_node_1/ancestor::*
```

If you want to get all *ancestor nodes names*:

```
//some_node_1/ancestor::*/name()
```